# DB2 JDBC messages

Tags: jdbc, db2, message

I'm using DB2 in my Java application. Language I have set on my machine is Slovenian. The exceptions I get in my program are in Slovenian language. Is there a way to set the language in which I want to get the exceptions?

Comment: Can you change the 'current' [locale](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0056651.html)?  This should be 'per-connection', and shouldn't persist otherwise.  I'm assuming either a system-wide default would have been set, or it's reading it from your machine (or did during setup).

Comment: Nope, since this locale only applies to procedures inside monreport module.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the regional setting for the user you are executing the command will change the language of the exceptions.

A better way, is to change the db2 installation, and remove any other language than English || or reinstall db2 in advanced mode with only English as language.

I speak Spanish, and the translation is kind horrible, words like table space or bufferpool are translated in a way that nobody understand the message.

Comment: Do you perhaps know of a way to do it on a installed, running database. I have couple of databases in production and I don't want to even run the installation program on those machines :)

Comment: I do not know how to change it without changing the installation, because DB2 takes the locale configuration of your machine, and because it is in Slovenian, and there is a message in Slovenian in the binaries, it will show it in this language.